# In Azure why can I not see a "Authorized client applications" section on the "Expose an API" page of an app registration

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I would like to pre-authorize an application on an exposed API (because it will be called via another API).

Everything I've found says that I should be able to do that on the "Expose an API" section of the app registration. You can even see that section in the first screenshot in this bit of Microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-expose-web-apis

However when I go to that page in Azure the "Authorized client applications" section is simply not there.

Is there a permission I might be missing, is this section hidden for certain app registration configurations, or is it something else?

[image]

Comment: As a side note about my overall goal, it seems to not be supported at the moment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/access-tokens#:~:text=Web%20API%20chains%20(On-Behalf,secured%20by%20Azure%20AD%20B2C.&text=However%2C%20the%20On-Behalf-,implemented%20in%20Azure%20AD%20B2C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design. The **Authorized client applications** function only exists in Azure AD. You are referring to the Azure AD documentation.

For Azure AD B2C application expose api, there is no `Add a client application` option, you should refer to [Azure AD B2C documentation](https://daniel-krzyczkowski.github.io/Cars-Island-ASP-NET-Core-API-Secured-By-Azure-AD-B2C/).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the documentation you link to doesn't help unfortunately - I have a service already set up like that. The problem I have is that that service then needs to call another service and pass the credentials on. Anyway, that's a separate question.