# How to authorize client application in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, authorize, clientid

Previously, we were using a registered app in Azure AD, but we want to switch over to Azure AD B2C now because it provides more identity provider options. The issue is that under "Expose an API" in my Azure AD app registration, there is a section "Authorized client applications" where you can specify the client id of a client application that you trust. However, in my B2C app registration, there is no "Authorized client applications" section under "Expose an API".

In Azure AD, I authorized client application with ID d3590ed6-52b3-4102-aeff-aad2292ab01c (Microsoft Office) and since I cannot do this the same way with Azure AD B2C, I am getting this error:

[image]

Any help on how I can solve this issue and authorize this client id in B2C would be appreciated, thank you.

I was expecting to find the option to authorize client applications in the same place, but perhaps it looks different in B2C.

Answer (score 0):

> **Note** that: The "Authorized client applications" section under Expose an API is only available in Azure AD but not in Azure AD B2C and this is by design.

You can access the **`ServerApp`** API using **`ClientApp`** in Azure AD B2C like below:

Create an **`ServerApp`**, Expose and API  and add scope:

[image]

Create an **`ClientApp`** and add this scope and grant Admin Consent:

[image]

Now, **authorize users**  to access **`ServerApp`** API using the below endpoint:

```json
https://rukkb2c.b2clogin.com/rukkb2c.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_testrukpolicy/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://rukkb2c.onmicrosoft.com/ClientID/access_as_user
&state=12345
```

[image]

I generated **access token** using below parameters via Postman:

```json
https://rukkb2c.b2clogin.com/rukkb2c.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_testrukpolicy/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:https://rukkb2c.onmicrosoft.com/ClientID/access_as_user
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

**References:**

[In Azure why can I not see a "Authorized client applications" section on the "Expose an API" page of an app registration - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66492508/in-azure-why-can-i-not-see-a-authorized-client-applications-section-on-the-ex) by Carl Zhao

[Request an access token in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/access-tokens)